# Oracle - output to Visual Studio

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, output

I'm trying to print something in Oracle SQL Developer to appear in a C++ console. That means, I connected my C++ program to an Oracle database and I'm calling several stored procedures through the Visual Studio. My question is this:

Is there any way I can print something in a procedure that will appear on C++ when I execute that procedure? Or do I have to query the database and handle the information on Visual Studio? I know this might sound weird but it would save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show something in your C++ program you will have to get the data from the stored procedure and then print it in the C++ program. Printing it in the stored procedure will not show up in your C++ program.

Comment: Which means I will have to query the database and print it normally. That's what I thought. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the way Oracle SQL Developer and many other Oracle tools do it:

- The stored procedures use the `DBMS_OUTPUT` package (`dbms_output.put_line`) to write text. The text goes into a session buffer.
- Oracle SQL Developer retrieves the text after each statement it has executed and displays it in the output view. It uses the `DBMS_OUTPUT` package (`dbms_output.get_lines`) as well.

See the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_output.htm) for more information.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't appear on the console which is what I need.